# IIS 7 leave connection after 20 sec

Tags: web-server, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-7

I have a song download portal, which is run under IIS7 web server configure with PHP v 5.4.24.Windows version 2012. Now , when we goes to download a song file link 4-6 mb then connection release after 20 sec and start downloading again after some time and then again release connection after 20 sec. But small file like 1 mb download properly. To resolve the issue, i have done below several changes into php.ini & IIS configuration.But problem still exists :

1. memory_limit = 512M [increase memory limit in php.ini].
2. default_socket_timeout = 600 [increase default socket time out value php.ini]
3. Set Idle Time-out=0 into IIS default application pool.

please suggest to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem. Just go to IIS->HTTP Response Headers-> Set Common Headers -> [Unmarked the option] Enable HTTP Keep Alive.[image]